# Why we cant return List<T> in ASMX web services?

Tags: c#, web-services, list, generics, asmx

As developers know we cant return `List<T>` with web services, we can only return lists with converting them to .ToArray(); I've searched some, but cant get effective answer about Why we cant retun List with web services. Why we must convert them ToArray(); ?

Comment: What sort of web service are you creating? That is, what technology is it using? WCF? ASMX?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Web services are supposed to be interoperable with many languages. Nearly all languages have arrays, but only .NET has the specific implementation of `List<T>` that you're using.

Comment: So, you mean because of the language standards, we use Array mostly??

Comment: I mean that web services don't let you use .NET only types by default, because the code calling the web service might not be .NET. As Stefan P pointed out, WCF (not asmx) web services allow you to specify that the client is .NET, in which case you can use .NET-specific types like `List<T>`.

Comment: Your answer make sense. You are right, but in my opinion, if List<T> is specific type in .Net, there should be specific allow to return List<T> with asmx web services :)

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing whatsoever preventing you from returning `List<T>` from an ASMX web service. I have no idea why you believe that.

What may be confusing you is that XML Schema (used by the WSDL) cannot describe "lists", per se. In fact, it cannot describe arrays, either. It can describe a series of repeating elements. All collections, including arrays, are returned as sets of repeating elements.

On the client side, the client has no way to know whether the server returned `List<T>`, `T[]`, or `IEnumerable<T>`, and no reason to care, either.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the interoperability settings of the webservice, an object like `int[]` is easier to understand for a non .NET language then `List<int>`. If you develop your web service under **WCF**, `List<T>` is supported as a return type.

Answer (score 1):

What's described in the web services is a "collection". It's up to the client to determine what type of "collection" to use. If the client's .Net, when adding the service reference, click Advanced, and you'll have the ability to choose a generic list.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware as long as you explicitly declare you are returning a List (of T) method title you can return the object; otherwise you will receive a serialize error.

e.g

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function Search(ByVal SearchTerm As String) As List(Of 'object here')
```