# Serialization Breaks on a Different Function

Tags: c#, ajax, file-upload, xml-serialization, asmx

I have an `.asmx` file with a bunch of functions beautifully decorated with

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
```

It works nicely for AJAX calls I make from the front-end code.

One of the functions has such a signature, and additional attribute

```
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public IEnumerable<MyUserType> GetSomeData()
```

It works as well as the others.

Lo and behold, another function, used for receiving files, is present on the same file. When calling this second function (it's a POST call, if that makes any difference) I get the infamous

```
System.NotSupportedException: Cannot serialize interface System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[MyLib.UserType, MyLib, Version=1.0.6098.20720, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].
```

I would note that aforementioned function is the only one using `MyUserType`, throughout the file.

Why is the *other* function throwing an error on the first?

**EDIT**

Calls for either function from webpage (jQuery) look like:

```
$.ajax({
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "/Service.asmx/GetSomeData",
        type: "GET"
    })
    .done(function (data) { ... })
```

And

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", new Blob([uploadFile]), uploadFile.File.name);
$.ajax({
        url: '/Service.asmx/UploadFile',
        type: "POST",
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        cache: false,
        data: formData,
        success: function (data) {
            //Shout hooray       
        }
    })
```

**EDIT**

Changing return type to `List` solved it, but I think there's still a question to answer here...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why we cant return List<T> in ASMX web services?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249000/why-we-cant-return-listt-in-asmx-web-services)

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy, I don't think so, because the function itself does work when I call it

Comment: I've edited the `ScriptMethod` in, maybe it's a clue

Comment: Post some code because the question is a bit confusing. I assume you are calling `GetSomeData()` from another webservice method, am i right?

Comment: AJAX, `UploadFile` as well. On same webpage

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy, added to question

Comment: Do you have `MyUserType` decorated with `[Serializable]`?

Comment: It's actually defined in another service, I get it serialized as XML.